# Library created with debug info when set release flags

Tags: android, c++, debugging, cmake, android-ndk

This is my shell command:

```
cmake .  \
      -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$toolchain \
      -DANDROID_NDK=$ndk_path \
      -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang \
      -DANDROID_ABI=$arc_abi \
      -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DANDROID_STL=c++_static

make
```

and in CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.5.1 )
project(husky)

set(prelibs "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../third_party/libs")
set(third_include "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../third_party/include")
set(src_root "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../src")

message(STATUS "cur dir:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

string(REPLACE "-Oz" "-O3" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
string(REPLACE "-Os" "-O3" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -std=c++14 -pthread -O3 -Wnon-virtual-dtor  -Wno-unused-parameter")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wextra -flto -fuse-ld=gold -Wl")

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release )

...
...

add_library(my_test
            SHARED
            ${ALGO_SRC_LIST}
            ${API_SRC_LIST}
            ${STAGE_SRC_LIST}
            ${UTILS_SRC_LIST}
            ${UTILS_CPU_LIST}
            ${UTILS_FORMAT_LIST}
            ${PIPELINE_SRC_LIST}
            )

target_link_libraries(my_test
        libopencv_imgproc
        libopencv_core
        libcpufeatures
        video
        libtbb
        libalgo
        libprotobuf
        ${EXTRA_LIBS}
        )
```

Whether I set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` or not, build library always has debuginfo. What's wrong with it?

update: my target is a dynamic library. when add "set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release )" in CMakeLists.txt or add "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" in cmake command， result is always a debug library。

Comment: Are you sure that you're not just looking at the unstripped version of the library? The stripped version can be found under app/build/intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol.

Comment: @Michael  I don't use android studio and gradle。 I only use camke and ndk toolchain.

Comment: What libraries are you referring to? The `third_party/libs` libraries? Are these debug libraries? Your CMake does not appear to create any library, unless you left out some section of your CMake.

Comment: sry, i omitted some codes , and now update CMakeList.txt and some details。i mean camke target library always is a debug library。

Comment: @squareskittles  as mentioned above